# how can I multiple this part using for loops?

Tags: python, abaqus

```
import section
    import regionToolset
    import displayGroupMdbToolset as dgm
    import part
    import material
    import assembly
    import step
    import interaction
    import load
    import mesh
    import optimization
    import job
    import sketch
    import visualization
    import xyPlot
    import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
    import connectorBehavior
    s = mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=5.0)
    g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
    s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)
    s.Line(point1=(-0.2, 0.2), point2=(-0.2, 0.1))
    s.VerticalConstraint(entity=g[2], addUndoState=False)
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(name='Part-1', dimensionality=THREE_D, 
        type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
    p.BaseWire(sketch=s)
    s.unsetPrimaryObject()
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1']
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p)
    del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to explain your question better. This is quite vague.

Comment: You might just create multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to create the same part many times. I would recommend just to copy it. But if you would really insist on using for loops you can do it like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    s = mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=5.0)
    g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
    s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)
    s.Line(point1=(-0.2, 0.2), point2=(-0.2, 0.1))
    s.VerticalConstraint(entity=g[2], addUndoState=False)
    p = mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(name='Part-'+str(i), dimensionality=THREE_D, 
        type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
    p.BaseWire(sketch=s)
    s.unsetPrimaryObject()
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p)
    del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']
```

If you clarify your question further I can update the answer.